# SOLR Schmaless Data Import: id is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig

Tags: solr4, dataimporthandler, solr5

I am trying to run data import handler with a core that is schemaless. But I am facing the above error. Should this error even happen with schemaless mode?

The SoLR version is 5.4.1. First I ran "./bin/solr -e schemaless". This generated the schemaless core in the example folder. Then I copied the file called rss-data-config.xml that comes from the SOLR data import handler example. I moved it to the example/schemaless/solr/gettingstarted/ folder of the schemaless core.

Then I changed the schemaless solrconfig.xml to support data import hander. I added the following lines:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">rss-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This leads SOLR to launch without problem. The data import handler also seems to be functioning. I can invoke it with a call to:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/dataimport?command=full-import
```

The only problem is what I see in the logs. Here is an excerpt:

```
  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.config.DIHConfiguration; id is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig
  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.config.DIHConfiguration; The field :date present in DataConfig does not have a counterpart in Solr Schema
  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.config.DIHConfiguration; The field :slash-section presentin DataConfig does not have a counterpart in Solr Schema
```

So, it appears the data import handler does not seem to go through the process that would create those fields.

Am I missing something? Is the DIH supposed to work with schemaless the way I expect it to?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am interested.